# How to define constants in php and access it from all files without including the constants file (any thing like AppSettings in .Net)

Tags: php, constants, magic-constants

I want define some constants and access those from any file without including any file in php.

**in the other word i search for any equivalent of Web.Config->AppSettings in C#**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define them in a file called **constants.php** and then change your `php.ini` settings so that this file is always loaded, before anything else:

```
auto_prepend_file = /var/www/website/constants.php
```

Comment: Thank u, is it possible to define auto_prepend_file in .htaccess file?